# Error 500 on /admin/user/permissions

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

For some reason, ctools/includes/plugins.inc is requiring an .inc file that doesn’t exist (and doesn’t need to exist in this custom module, as far as I know), and on /admin/user/permissions, that’s what it’s blaming for the 500 error. Other admin pages are fine. This is also making drush throw a lot of errors on drush cc all.

Error in dblog and syslog:

> require_once(./sites/SITENAME/modules/CUSTOM/MODULENAME/SundialParser.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\PATH\acquia-drupal-1.2.21\sites\SITENAME\modules\ctools\includes\plugins.inc on line 770.

PHP 5.2.17
PHP memory limit 256MB
Ctools 6.x-1.12

Stuff I’ve tried that hasn’t worked:

- adding and enabling the filter permissions module
- changing the admin theme
- increasing php memory
- manually truncating cache tables

Existing discussions:

- [Error 500 only on permissions page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/error-500-only-on-permissions-page)
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1775612 (this is for D7 but seems like the same problem)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In drush or dblog?

Comment: Most of the time a 500 will leave a proper error message in the server logs (sometimes you'll see it in the watchdog, sometimes not, depends on config). You mentioned an include file missing, it would be useful to see the full error message, and maybe to know the name of your module

Comment: Edited in the exact error message. The module is a custom one that hasn't been touched in...a while. (It's a legacy site I inherited, and a module I have never touched.)